# What underlying semantic notions connect the stem '-festus' to the PIE root *gu̯hedh- ('to ask, beg, wish for')?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

> Pokorny Etymon: [g<sup>u̯</sup>hedh-](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex_reflex/2966)   'to ask, beg, wish for'
>
> Semantic Field(s): to Ask, Request, to Will, Wish
>
> [...]
>
> Italic
> Latin:    -festus         [suffix]    hit     W7

What semantic notions underlie 'hit' to the Semantic Fields above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This etymology is based on the assumption that infestus “hostile” comes from Indo-European *n-gwhedh-to- “implacable”. There are serious semantic and phonetic problems with this theory (which are spelt out in de Vaan’s Latin etymological dictionary, s.v. “infestus”). I would recommend that you take the Texas site with a very large grain of salt. It is particularly annoying that it mixes up loan words (like English “infest”) with cognates. Anyway, festus is not a "suffix", but a stem.